# Node.js: Not able to return Mongoose find results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to Node.JS and can't find a solution to this. 
I'm building a restful service to retrieve data from mongo.

app.js

```
var database = require('./database.js');
...

app.get('/metadata', function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET: metadata");
    res.send(database.getMetadata(null));
});

app.get('/metadata/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET: metadata");
    res.send(database.getMetadata(req.params.id));
});
...
```

database.js

```
exports.getMetadata = function (id) {
    console.log('getting metada...')
    if (id == null) {
        return FolderInfo.find({}, null, null, function (err, metadatas) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(metadatas);
                return metadatas;
            } else {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        return FolderInfo.findById(id, function (err, metadatas) {
            if (!err) {
                return metadatas;
            } else {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried many different approaches. But always get this as result:

```
{
    options: {
        populate: { }
    },
    _conditions: { },
    _updateArg: { },
    op: "find"
}
```

but my *console.log(metadatas);* line is printing the results to the console.
I'm using all the latest packages.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you mean that even when you provide an id parameter in the GET request, the generic find (instead of the findByID) is being called?

Comment: If not, what is the behavior you are hoping for?

Comment: The find method seems to work because the console.log inside the callback prints the results, but it's not what I get back in the response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really mix synchronous `return`s with asynchronous functions like `findById`, as it goes against the basic nature of asynchronous operations: "*exit now, complete later*."

You'll have to adjust `getMetadata` to accept a callback function that can be called when `findById` has *completed later*:

```
exports.getMetadata = function (id, callback) {
   // ...
};
```

And, instead of returning `metadatas` only when there's not an `err`:

```
if (!err) {
    return metadatas;
} else {
   // ...
}
```

You'll want to call the `callback` in either case:

```
callback(err, err ? null : metadatas);
```

In context, that could be:

```
FolderInfo.find({}, null, null, function (err, metadatas) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(metadatas);
    }

    callback(err, err ? null : metadatas);
});
```

Or possibly just:

```
FolderInfo.find({}, null, null, callback);
```

Then pass `getMetadata` a callback function that handles the response when called:

```
app.get('/metadata', function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET: metadata");
    database.getMetadata(null, function (err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan! Your answer not only helped me to solve my problem but also helped me to understand more about the way Node.Js handles things.